# nodejs/mongodb: Pass a value to an exec child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, child-process

I'm creating a childprocess when an express api is called after saving some info in mongodb. This is the api part

```js
router.get("/create", function(req, res) {

  let Schema = new New({
    Id: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex"),
    Status: "Online"
  });

  Schema.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      let child = exec(`node ${modulepath}`, (error, stdout) => {
        if (error) {
          throw error;
        }
        console.log(child.stdout);
      });

      New.update({
        "botId": Schema.Id
      }, {
        "ProcessId": child.pid
      }).then((err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("pid updated");
        }
      });
      Id = Schema.Id;
      module.exports = {
        Id
      };
    }
  });
});
```

What i'm trying to do here is, at the bottom i'm exporting an id which ideally should be exported to the childprocess instance but that is not happening. In the childprocess, if i import the id by `const Id = require("./routes").Id;` and try to access some info through it by

```js
await New.findOne({
  "Id": Id
}, function(err, b) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    //some task
  }
});
```

I'm not able to access the info as mongodb cant get the id. I know i'm going wrong in passing the value to the childprocess part but what is the solution?

Comment: The child process can't access variables stored in the main process memory. There are many ways to pass that variable to the child process depending on your requirements; for example you can pass it via a command line argument, an environment variable, via the database, by using node.js builtin IPC channel [see `child_process.fork`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), or even a lightweight message queue such as [zeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/).

Comment: @fardjad Thanx. Passing value by command line did the job.

Comment: Glad I could help. You might want to answer your own question and maybe include some code so other people that stumble upon this question will know how to pass data to other executables via command line arguments.